# Thai Tourist Visa and Exemption

Tags: tourist-visas, borders, thailand

Your opinion or expertise would be appreciated.

I entered Thailand with an exemption Stamp on 10 SEP 2019. Flew out on 12 SEP 2019 to Cambodia with friends.

Re-entered Thailand on an exemption Stamp on 17 SEP 2019.

Flew to Phnom Penh to obtain a 60/90 Day Visa on 16 OCT 2019.

Obtained VISA and returned to Thailand via Air on 20 OCT 2019.

Received 30 Day Extenstion on 13 DEC 2019 (to 18 JAN 2020).

Flew back to Phnom Penh on 13 JAN 2020 to apply for another 60/90 Day Tourist Visa.

I was refused.

The only question that the official at the counter asked was why I hadn't used the exit ticket that I'd shown as proof for my last Tourist Visa.

I answered her that I had planned to go home for Christmas but had changed my mind because I had started taking Muaythai instruction and had wanted to continue the lessons and that I was now planning to go back to the States for the Spring instead. She asked for proof. I gave her my schedule and cont

act details for my Muaythai instructor.

The "consulate" refused my visa.

Will that preclude my entering on a Visa Exemption stamp?

I was contemplating flying over to Laos and attempting to enter via the land border. I'm nervous though, that I'm in the system as "refuse entry" or something.

I don't deal drugs. I don't have a job. I've got plenty of money in the bank and, of course, provided a bank statement. I provided a schedule for the Thai boxing lessons and contact details for my instructor. I am from the US if that matters.

It seems that the sticking point was that I didn't fly out in accordance with the ticket that I'd used for my last Visa application. I don't want to fly in to Suvarnabhumi as I don't want to risk being deported back to the States.

Any insight would be appreciated.